# Errors Scatterplot: SVM Regression

Tags: r, regression, svm, scatter-plot

I would like to understand more on how to interpret an Errors Scatterplot** . Thank you very much,

I ran this code:

```
plot(bronxts$SOLD_PRICE,preds_br, main='Errors Scaterplot for Bronx',
ylab='Predictions',xlab='True')
abline(0,1,col='red',lty=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The scatterplot is simply showing the relationship between the 'True' price and the 'Predicted' price. The red dashed line serves as a reference for model predictions that perfectly predict the true price. So, circles that fall below the dashed line represent UNDERpredictions while the circles above the line represent OVERpredictions.